# Breeze hiding arrays from knockoutjs foreach

Tags: knockout.js, breeze

I have a complex graph.  Within the graph there are 
a) types with arrays and 
b) arrays of types with arrays within them.

I'm loading the graph using Breezejs and passing that to knockoutjs (2.2.1).

It seems that I can do a foreach over the arrays in the a) type but can't foreach over the contained arrays in the b) types. In other words the b) types are themselves looped over and an inner loop for the contained arrays.  Simple elements in the b) types show up in the knockout html output but not the arrays.

For example:  the main graph is a physician.  A physician has a single ContactInfo (type 'a' from above) type which contains the First/Last names etc.  Contained in ContactInfo are arrays of Addresses, Phone# and emails.  These all list out fine using data-bind="foreach: ContactInfo().Addresses()"

Also contained in the physician graph is an array of Memberships (a type 'b' above) that the physician can belong to.
The phys.Memberships[].Organization contains a Name for the organization etc.  It also has an array of Fee types (phys.Memberships[].Fees[]) that contain an amount.  I can get the organization name but not the fee.Amount.

If I take the json literal that's returned from the server and paste it into a variable eliminating any magic that Breezejs performs on the data to make them ko.observables I'm able to access the b) types and their internal arrays but not if I pass the data from the success method of the breeze call into the viewModel.

I'd paste the json graph litteral but it's over 500 lines.

I'm just wondering if this is a known limitation of breezejs or am I doing something wrong.

Here's the viewmodel:

```
  var PhysiciansModel = function (physicians) {
    var self = this;
    self.showPhysList = ko.observable(false),
    self.physicians = ko.observableArray(physicians);
    self.selectedPhys = ko.observable(),
    self.selectedPhysIndex = ko.observable(),
    self.selectedPhysGraph = ko.observable(),
    self.save = function () {
      saveChanges();
    };
    self.getPhysByInitial = function (item, event) {
      getPhysList(event.target.textContent);
      self.showPhysList(true);
    };
    self.clickOnPhys = function (phys, event) {
      if (self.selectedPhys() == null || (phys.Id() !== self.selectedPhys().Id())) {
        self.selectedPhys(phys);
        self.selectedPhysIndex(event.target.parentElement.parentElement.id);
        getPhysGraph(self.selectedPhys().Id());
        self.showPhysList(false);
      }
    };
  };
```

Thanks

Comment: Please post your viewModel code, at the very least (although some sample lines of the graph literal would also be nice)

Comment: You can also post your code to http://jsonfiddle.net/ although SO would rather you posted it here.